# Linq Query that returns IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method called

```
     public static IQueryable GetUsers()
```

uses Linq query.

```
{SELECT [t0].[ApplicationUserId], ([t0].[LastName] + @p0) + [t0].[FirstName] AS [UserName], [t1].[SecurityRoleName], [t2].[UserStatus]
    FROM [dbo].[ApplicationUsers] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoles] AS [t1] ON [t0].[SecurityRoleId] = [t1].[SecurityRoleID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserStatusLookups] AS [t2] ON [t0].[UserStatusId] = [t2].[UserStatusLookupID]
    ORDER BY [t0].[LastName]
}
```

that returns all the users. I cannot the change this method or class.

I need a user belonging to a specific security role. From just IQueryable would I be able to get a specific user. 
so that `[t1].[SecurityRoleID]` is replaced with 15.

Comment: what you are displaying looks like the sql generated by a linq query... You question is a little unclear would be able to expand on it a little?

Comment: That is the linq returned by the method call. In that I wanted to include a where class so that I can get only users belonging to role ID = 15

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Where` because it's only defined on [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), the strongly-typed version. You need to cast your `IQueryable` from `GetUsers()` to an appropriate `IQueryable<T>`:

```
var users = GetUsers().Cast<ModelType>();
```

`ModelType` should be whatever type the model objects from `GetUsers` are; it should have `SecurityRoleID`, `ApplicationUserId`, or whatever properties you need.

Then you can use the LINQ extension methods:

```
var user = users.Where(u => u.SecurityRoleID == 15);
```

or maybe:

```
var user = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.SecurityRoleID == 15);
```

Comment: +1 was about to post the same observation about `IQueryable` versus `IQueryable<T>`. It's unfortunate that the OP's method was defined that way. From MSDN: *The IQueryable interface is intended for implementation by query providers. It is only supposed to be implemented by providers that also implement IQueryable<T>. If the provider does not also implement IQueryable<T>, the standard query operators cannot be used on the provider's data source.*

Comment: @Kalls - you might have to do the coercion manually ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)), unless you can specify `ModelType` as whatever type the objects in the Queryable already are.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var Role15Users = GetUsers().Where(t => t.SecurityRoldID == 15);
```

Comment: I am not able to use Where with the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a where on your full list

```
var users = MyClass.GetUsers();
var userInRole = users.Where(u=>u.SecurityRoleId == 15);
```

Comment: I am not able to use Where as the intellisense doesn't allow me to.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
using System.Linq
```

in your includes?

`Where<TSource> Method (IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>)`

is an extension method to the IQueryable type found in the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is also quite possible that there's no `SecurityRoleId` property in the class, rather an object relation. In this case you would have to write something like

```
var roleUsers = dataSource.GetUsers().Where(
    u => u.SecurityRole.Id == 15
    );
```

It would return all users with role #15.
However you sure must know that magic number are bad.

If you want to find a *single* user with role called, for instance, `Admin`, make sure SecurityRole is correctly mapped (depends on your class structure which you haven't posted) and do something like

```
var admin = (from user in dataSource.GetUsers()
            where user.SecurityRole.Name == "Administrator"
            select user).Single(); // will throw exception if none or multiple are found


var admin = (from user in dataSource.GetUsers()
            where user.SecurityRole.Name == "Administrator"
            select user).SingleOrDefault(); // will return null if none, throw exception if multiple are found
```

You can also rewrite these queries in method call fashion:

```
var admin = dataSource.GetUsers()
    .Where(u => u.SecurityRole.Name == "Administrator")
    .Single(); // will throw exception if none or multiple are found

var admin = dataSource.GetUsers()
    .Where(u => u.SecurityRole.Name == "Administrator")
    .SingleOrDefault(); // will return null if none, throw exception if multiple are found
```